# How to use gm_authFailure of google maps api?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to catch an error if google maps API key is invalid, but I don't have any idea how to use this function.

```
function gm_authFailure() {alert('Error');}.
```

I've tried putting it on the global scope but it just can't catch the error.

```
<script>
    gm_authFailure();
    function gm_authFailure() {
        alert('Error');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Literally just pasted the code at the end of my HTML code and google automatically calls the function if there's an error.